# Enable php-logging on server of godaddy hosted wordpress

Tags: php, logging, server, http-status-code-500

for about a day I'm trying to find a way to see php logs on a server by godaddy where wordpress is hosted.
I can ssh to the server, but I'm not able to edit the php.ini because it's readonly.
I've read that it would be possible to add a custom php.ini to change some settings. I've put one in the public folder where the wordpress site is located and added the line:

```
error_log = "/php_error.log"
```

In the same folder I've created the file php_error.log and set the following permissions:

-rw-rw----

As this seemed not to work, I've tried an approach editing the .htaccess file.

```
# log php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log /php_error.log
```

Still I don't see any errors in the file.
Is it a problem of the permissions of the error file or should the path be different e.g. html/php_error.log ?

Comment: Why don't you just ask godaddy support where to find the error log file?

Comment: Looks like this could be your file path. You are setting it to `/php_error.log` so this would be in the root directory of the server.

If you can ssh into the server you can find the working directory using the `pwd` command. Use that output as the folder directory for you error log. If this does not help you may need to chat to GoDaddy. Good luck!

Comment: I've called them already before asking the question here. They've sent me two articles which should help me getting the logs, but so far I'm still failing. pwd was a good hint, however I've tried all variations of the path and it didn't achieve to see any logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a solution.
I have to create a .user.ini file to set custom settings of php.ini.
I've put the file in the root of my public website directory and inserted the following line:

```
error_log = "/var/www/php_error.log"
```

It took me quite a while to figure out what the expected path to my log file is. Hopefully this will save some other people a lot of time and headache.